# Wrong Chromecast buttons position with RTL (right-to-left)

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am using googlecast [example](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios).

When I show GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController, all the buttons are in the correct position.

[image]

But when I use this part of the code, the buttons overlap each other.

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

I don't know if this is important, but the language in the iPhone settings - English.

This is the result that I get

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't support RTL well now. You can file a feature request here https://developers.google.com/cast/support